# Docker CMD command is not running

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I've created Dockerfile that is running gui, and after the container is executed I want it to run some bash script without freezing the container, so I am trying to run it as a background process but it seems like it's not executed at all.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM dorowu/ubuntu-desktop-lxde-vnc:latest
WORKDIR /data

COPY ./startup.sh /tmp/
COPY ./procedure.sh /tmp/

RUN chmod +x /tmp/startup.sh
RUN chmod +x /tmp/procedure.sh

CMD ["/tmp/startup.sh"]
```

startup.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /tmp && nohup ./procedure.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

procedure.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 5

whoami > /tmp/log.txt

output=$(cat /tmp/log.txt)
```

My expectation is to have `startup.sh` executed when the container is started, and then run `procedure.sh` that will call to all of my flow.

As you can see I am printing the log into `/tmp/log.txt` but actually nothing is getting created once the container is started.

If I am running the script `/tmp/startup.sh` manually I can see the `log.txt` is getting created properly.

I will appreciate your help!

Comment: Swap `CMD` with `ENTRYPOINT`

Comment: @Paolo, After replacing `CMD` with `ENTRYPOINT` the container is not starting at all, I am running `docker run ....` and no container starts

Comment: What does the `docker run` command look like?

Comment: @Paolo, `docker run -p 5900:5900  -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm image`

Comment: How are you assessing that nothing gets created? Since your container is a short lived one and that you are not mounting the folder `/tmp` to see the content of `log.txt`, when the container dies, the file vanish with it.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε, Please notice this is a GUI container that is running forever and never die until I kill the process manually.

Comment: @Itzik.B you seems to have an issue understanding the relation between CMD and ENTRYPOINT in Docker, may I suggest you reading the relevant documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact?

Comment: Also mind that your main image does simply ignore your CMD, as you can see by yourself in their entrypoint script not doing anything with with the arguments it receives: https://github.com/fcwu/docker-ubuntu-vnc-desktop/blob/develop/rootfs/startup.sh

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate because your command exits, and when that happens, the container stops. That happens immediately in your case since the command launches a background process and exits.